# NodeJS GCP Datastore Unable To Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore

I am trying to query the user by the Datastore auto-generated ID.

Below GQL query is able to run on `Datastore Console` 
`select * from User where __key__ = Key(User, 123)`

But JS code using [Datastore JS Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore), doesn't work and returning empty list.

```
const filterKey = dataStore.key(['User', 123]);

dataStore.runQuery(dataStore.createQuery(relationEntity).filter('__key__', filterKey));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I see with your query is that you are missing the [comparison operator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#key_filters) inside the `filter` clause. Aside from that, what does `relationEntity` hold? To mimic your GQL query, it should be the `kind` name of the entities you want to fetch. I made this query to fetch entities based on your GQL query `select * from User where __key__ = Key(User, 123)`:

```js
const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");

const datastore = new Datastore();
//Kind = “User”, ID = 5634161670881280, using [default] namespace

const entKey = datastore.key(["User", 5634161670881280]);
const query = datastore.createQuery("User").filter("__key__", "=", entKey); 

datastore.runQuery(query).then(([entities]) => {
    entities.forEach((entity) => {
        console.log(entity.firstname) // prints “Foo” which is the ‘firstname’ in my entity
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Something else that could be a cause is the JS number limit, and in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest/datastore/key), it’s mentioned that you would need to wrap your auto-generated ID inside `datastore.int(“<YOUR_ID>”)` for large numbers. If you’d like to see more sample code, there are a lot of snippets in the Datastore Github [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/tree/main/samples). Let me know if this was useful.